# SQL Server with multiple installs: evaluation period has ended and SSIS packages failing

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've inherited a SQL Server box that I'm not an expert on. At the time I installed SSMS 2014 to keep an eye on the daily SSIS jobs that were running on it. I think because I'm an idiot and used the 2014 evaluation copy of SSMS, once that evaluation period stopped, the jobs stopped.

I have SSMS 2016 installed on the same machine. Is there a way to get the SSIS jobs running again if I just uninstall 2014 and use 2016 instead?

> Executed as user: [***]. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 12.0.2000.8 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
>   Started:  8:00:00 AM
>
>   Error: 2017-04-03 08:00:00.76
>
>   Code: 0xC0000033
>
>   Source: ***
>   Description:
>   Integration Services evaluation period has expired.
>   End Error
>
> Error: 2017-04-03 08:00:00.76
>   Code: 0xC0000033
>   Source: ***
>   Description:
>   Integration Services evaluation period has expired.
>   End Error
>
> Could  not execute package because of error 0xC0000033.
>
> Started:  8:00:00 AM
>   Finished: 8:00:00 AM    Elapsed:  0.187 seconds.
>   The command line parameters are invalid. The step failed.

For clarity, here's a rough chronology of events that's led up to here:

- Feb - given access to workstation while current maintainer of it is preparing to leave. Two accounts set up on the OS (just regular old windows 10): his and mine. I install SQL Server Management Studio 2014 so I can access the DB on the computer
- Mar - I need access to an Azure SQL data warehouse, so I need to install SSMS 2016 for integrated authentication which isn't supported in SSMS 2014. I installed SQL Server 2016 on 3/14.
- Apr - old manager of the system leaves and his account is deactivated. This is when I start getting issues with 2014 saying its evaluation period has expired. This is probably true since I think I skipped putting a product key in it at the time of install. The Sql Server Agent jobs tied to the DB started failing shortly after.

Comment: That message says that the *server* has expired, not just SSMS. Was the inherited database a *trial* version?

Comment: To clarify, the message indicates that Integration Services has expired, _not_ SQL Server.

Comment: It sounds like the version of integration services that was installed wasn't licensed and the license has expired...  This has nothing to do with SSMS. You should check out your SQL Server installation and configuration (not SSMS installation/configuration).

Comment: As currently written, this question isn't entirely clear.  Are you trying to connect to SQL Server on the local workstation or another computer?  Was another version of SQL Server installed before you installed SQL Server 2014 or 2016 on the computer?  Are you connecting to the right instance? Are you connecting to the right computer?  Did you install SQL Server 2014/2016, or __just__ SSMS 2014/2016? It's tough to help you here.

Comment: Hi Dan, sorry for the confusion. There was a SQL Server 2014 instance set up when I arrived. I then installed 2014 and 2016 Integration Services Feature Pack for Azure. On 3/14 I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2016. I can connect to the database no problem, it's only the SQL Server Agent jobs that are failing due to the error in my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not totally clear what the issue was, but it's been resolved now. I went into my installation center of SQL Server 2014 and input a product key for it. After the upgrade, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

SSMS is a separate free product now, with monthly updates. Uninstall the old version, then [download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) and install the latest one. The latest version at this point is 16.5.3.

Don't download 17.0 RC3, it's still missing some important features.

BTW SSIS jobs aren't executed by SSMS. They are executed by SQL Server Agent. Once you install SSMS 16.5.3 you need to check the job history to see why they stopped, what errors occured etc.

If there is a problem with the SSIS package, you'll have to check the package's Execution history. Open the Integration Services Catalog, find the package, right click on it and select `Reports > All Executions`.

Comment: Possibly dumb question on my part: so if I go about uninstalling SSMS 2012 and 2016 (current 2016 version I have is 13.0.16106.4) then re-install SSMS 2016 16.5.3, should that fix the SSIS package execution problem? I posted the error output from the logs in my original post.

Comment: No, SSIS execution has nothing at all to do with the client tool. SSMS is nothing more than a client tool

Comment: Wait - that message says that your entire server is a trial that's expired. Can you even connect to the database at this point? How did the *trial* version of the SSIS server component get installed?